# ServiceInstaller.Uninstall does not stop service on Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

There is a strange behaviour.

I have the followed code:

```
ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();
InstallContext installContext = new InstallContext();
serviceInstaller.Context = installContext;
serviceInstaller.ServiceName = strServiceName;
serviceInstaller.Uninstall(null);
```

It's everything OK on Windows 7, but it does not work on Windows 10.

I have to stop the service explicitly (by `ServiceController.Stop()` ), to be able to uninstall it on Windows 10.

As described in MSDN, `ServiceInstaller.Uninstall ()` tried to stop service, but continued to work without any exception, if stopping was failed.

> Uninstall first attempts to stop the service before uninstalling it.
>   If the service cannot be stopped, no exception is caught, and the
>   method continues with the removal of the service.

It there any difference on stopping of a thread in Windows 7 and Windows 10? Or maybe `ServiceInstaller.Uninstall ()` does not try to stop service on Windows 10?

Comment: This issue meems to be related to Creator Update. I've tryed to execute my program on Windows 10 without new Creator Update and it works fine...